# I need to save the video before uploading

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, video, upload

I have an application that has the possibility to record a video and to upload it.
After i get the video from UIImagePickerView i upload it using a PUT method using ASIHTTPRequest.

I get memory warnings and sometimes the upload times out.
I was thinking that i have to save the video before uploading.

What is the best solution for my problem?

Regards,
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know how big your video is, but I think either **AVFoundation** or **MediaPlayer** have methods for getting specific frames out of the video.

If you get out of memory, you can get either split it up to frames and upload each one of them  in a loop, or split the video in n-second parts, where n seconds is a sub video that has good uploading time and good memory footprint.

I already have used in a project **AVAssetImageGenerator**, to get **UIImages** from a video and upload them, and it worked fine.

Comment: If i split the video to frames and upload each one of them in a loop, does the WS has to be modified to glue those frames back together? Same thing for n seconds subvideos.

Comment: yes you have to "reassemble" in the server part. As long as you send the place of the frame / n-part in the whole video, reassembling should be relatively easy.